# How to remove link around the_attachment_link image in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

This is what I have in the loop that grabs the posts and displays them on the index page...

```
<?php the_attachment_link( $attachment->ID , false); ?>
```

And this is what it results in...

```
<a href="linkToImage">
    <img src="sorceOfImage"/>
</a>
```

I just want that middle part without having it wrapped in a link. Any ideas? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about this:

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $id ); ?>
```

outputs something like http://example.net/wp-content/uploads/filename

Comment: Thanks! This in combination with timThumb will work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the image only:

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID ); ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image

Comment: That would be great however wordpress doesn't necessarily know that this is an image that is attached. I built a custom form that posts from the font end and wordpress only knows that it's an attachment, not that it's an image necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php 
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'any',
        'post_parent' => $post->ID
    );

    $attachments = get_posts($args);
    if ($attachments) : ?>
    <ul>            
        <?php foreach($attachments as $attachment): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID, true); ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID, true); ?>" width="100%"/>
            <h3><?php echo $attachment->post_title; ?></h3></a>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>

    <?php endif; ?>


<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```